# Did Apollo-11 have any radiation shielding?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, radiation

If it did, then what kind? Or if it didn't, was it because the flight didn't last for too long? (7 days or so, from Earth to Moon and back.)

Comment: A combination of a radiation measurements were taken via probes to assess the risk, short duration of the journey & weight restrictions for the space craft. The skin on the lunar module was so thin it could have been easily punctured with a pencil, if I recall correctly a statement made by Buzz Aldrin in one of his books. While traveling to & from the Moon & while on the Moon, most astronauts reported seeing strange flashes of light. This was later attributed to cosmic radiation hitting the retinas of the astronauts eyes.

Comment: The heat shield of the Command module had a shielding against solar radiation. The heat shield has several outer coverings: a pore seal, a moisture barrier (a white reflective coating), and a silver Mylar thermal coating that looks like aluminum foil. The silver mylar coating was a shield against IR, visible light and invisible UV radiation as well as low energy alpha rays.

Comment: I agree that it is a duplicate of the question specified by @Hobbes; however, note that the answer is in the *non-accepted* answer of that question.